# Realm sometimes doesn't return latest results

Tags: ios, swift, realm

Most of the time it I get all the results, but sometimes I don't, and that's obviously a problem. I have a function like:

```
func addProduct(thisProduct:Product) {
    let realm = try! Realm()
    try! realm.write {
        realm.add(thisProduct)
    }
    countProductsAddedToday() 
    // sometimes doesn't include the just added product to the count
}
```

The problem is my function `countProductsAddedtoday()` is not always returning the correct number of products when called immediately after a write transaction like in this case. If it gets called later (by tapping a button in my app), it returns the right count.
I'm hoping this is a common problem and that I'm doing something I'm not supposed to be doing.

The function `countProductsAddedToday()` is like this:

```
func countProductsAddedToday() -> Int {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeAdded >= %d", unixTimestampForToday)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    let results = realm.objects(Product).filter(predicate)
    return results.count
}
```

Additional information: I can't be sure but I think the problem happens more often when adding products quickly, but then stops happening. Is there some delayed writing or caching of results or something like that?

The error I'm getting when adding products on a physical device:

```
0   Realm                               0x000000010042d7e0 _ZN5realm4util18terminate_internalERNSt3__118basic_stringstreamIcNS1_11char_traitsIcEENS1_9allocatorIcEEEE + 44
1   Realm                               0x000000010042da0c _ZN5realm4util9terminateEPKcS2_l + 340
2   Realm                               0x00000001002a70ac _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator19run_async_notifiersEv + 2124
3   Realm                               0x00000001002a6668 _ZN5realm5_impl16RealmCoordinator9on_changeEv + 40
4   Realm                               0x000000010026adf4 _ZN5realm5_impl20ExternalCommitHelper6listenEv + 672
5   Realm                               0x000000010026b89c _ZZN5realm5_impl20ExternalCommitHelperC1ERNS0_16RealmCoordinatorEENK3$_0clEv + 24
6   Realm                               0x000000010026b878 _ZNSt3__112__async_funcIZN5realm5_impl20ExternalCommitHelperC1ERNS2_16RealmCoordinatorEE3$_0JEE9__executeIJEEEvNS_15__tuple_indicesIJXspT_EEEE + 64
7   Realm                               0x000000010026b82c _ZNSt3__112__async_funcIZN5realm5_impl20ExternalCommitHelperC1ERNS2_16RealmCoordinatorEE3$_0JEEclEv + 24
8   Realm                               0x000000010026b73c _ZNSt3__119__async_assoc_stateIvNS_12__async_funcIZN5realm5_impl20ExternalCommitHelperC1ERNS3_16RealmCoordinatorEE3$_0JEEEE9__executeEv + 32
9   Realm                               0x000000010026bfc0 _ZNSt3__114__thread_proxyINS_5tupleIJMNS_19__async_assoc_stateIvNS_12__async_funcIZN5realm5_impl20ExternalCommitHelperC1ERNS5_16RealmCoordinatorEE3$_0JEEEEEFvvEPSB_EEEEEPvSG_ + 388
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000180cebb28 <redacted> + 156
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000180ceba8c <redacted> + 0
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x0000000180ce9028 thread_start + 4
```

Comment: Is `countProductsAddedToday()` being called on the same thread as your sample code indicates, or is it being dispatched to a different queue or thread?

Comment: I've tried both, the same problem exists in both cases.

Comment: I've tested this on a simulator. Now I tried it on a physical device (adding 1 product every second), and it seemed to work fine, but then I got a crash `realm_coordinator.cpp:435: [realm-core-0.97.4] Assertion failed: m_advancer_sg->get_version_of_current_transaction() == new_notifiers.front()->version()`, repeated the whole thing and it happened again. Obviously, users will not be adding a product every second, but I like whatever's happening to be consistent, and there is something I don't understand happening here.

Comment: Now on a physical device I don't even have to add it every second, the crash happens randomly. If you need any more information, holler.

Comment: @TimSim: If you can reproduce this crash with the latest version of Realm, could you please create an issue for it on our [repo](https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa)? Thanks!

Comment: @marius I have updated to the latest version (assuming all I had to do is _pod update_) and no crashes have happened so far (in around 200 tries, whereas it was causing a crash after 5-6 tries).

Comment: @bdash It was my fault, nothing to do with Realm. The `unixTimestampForToday` was sometimes wrong because I liked eating lead paint as a kid.

Comment: Happy to hear that you tracked down the problem! The assertion failure you mentioned hitting has been fixed in Realm v0.99.1, FWIW.

Answer (score 2):

Change your function to:

```
func countProductsAddedToday() -> Int {
    let predicate = NSPredicate(format: "timeAdded >= %d", unixTimestampForToday)
    let realm = try! Realm()
    realm.refresh()
    let results = realm.objects(Product).filter(predicate)
    return results.count
}
```

Comment: This answer is what you're looking for in multi-threading scenarios. You'll need to refresh the Realm on any background thread before you see the latest results. The same applies for the main thread, if you wrote from a background thread and dispatch to the main thread directly after writing.

Comment: The problem was due to my stupidity - the `unixTimestampForToday` was sometimes the current second instead of midnight, so when the insert operation started during one second and the count happened in another, I wouldn't get the latest product, that's why it seemed inconsistent.